# Issue importing Material's sidenav on a Progressive Web App (Angular2)

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cli, progressive-web-apps

After finishing Angular's MobileToolkit guide (https://github.com/angular/mobile-toolkit/blob/master/guides), I wanted to bring some extra components to my app... like a sidenav!

Just like the tutorial taught me, I added all the code needed to use the SideNav component...

Here's my app.component.ts imports:

[image]

Here's the directives registration:

[image]

The external packages added (first two are from the mentioned tutorial):

[image]

And all the exports (again, from the tutorial):

[image]

Having all that in place, I execute the "ng serve" command and.... meh:

[image]

After some research, I found similar issues around the web, but most of them were either related to a missing angular package (http) or to old Angular2 versions. That is not the case here, since I'm using the latest versions and http package is in place (inside both node_modules and dist folders)

If you want to dig deeper: https://github.com/d0cz/t-tracker/tree/master

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yesterday I had a similar problem whic got solved `updating angular-cli-build.js` such as the following (see at the bottom @angular2-material entry)

```
/* global require, module */

var Angular2App = require('angular-cli/lib/broccoli/angular2-app');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  return new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: [
      'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
      'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
      'zone.js/dist/*.js',
      'es6-shim/es6-shim.js',
      'reflect-metadata/*.js',
      'rxjs/**/*.js',
      '@angular/**/*.js',
      '@angular2-material/**/*.js'
    ]
  });
};
```

I hope this helps

**UPDATE**

It could be that you are missing

```
  '@angular2-material/core': {
    format: 'cjs',
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    main: 'core.js'
  }
```

in system-config.js

**UPDATE 2 - open sidenav**

here is the code I use to open the sidenav

```
<md-sidenav #sidenav (open)="mybutton.focus()" align="start">
     ......
  </md-sidenav>

    <button (click)="sidenav.toggle()"></button>
```

Notice that the click of the button fires the toggle() method of sidenav. This is a demo I found on angular2-material  https://github.com/jelbourn/material2-app

Comment: Hey!! Thanks for the response, but unfortunately the error is still there :(

Comment: Did restart the server? Check if you have @angular2-material in the directory dist/vendor

Comment: it's there.. and yes, I've restarted the server!

Comment: I have updated my answer with the last thing that I see. Hopefully it is usefull

Comment: Thanks Sir! The error is now gone! (weirdly, the sidenav is still not being displayed...)

Comment: In my code I had to open it explicitely through code

Comment: I am clearly being dumb here.. just can't get the md-sidenav to work properly

Comment: I edited my answer with few details on opening the sidenav

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112531/discussion-between-bruno-wolff-and-picci).